# Problema com posição de vetores

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma aplicação no qual eu fiz uma uma arrylist de imagens, que nessa lista da imagem tem sua posição, no método onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));

    // clicar nas imagens e setar
    holder.imageView.setTag(position);
    holder.Baixar.setTag(position);
    holder.aplicar.setTag(position);


    if (ChecandoseExisteIMG(nomes[position])){
         holder.Baixar.setText("Baixado.");
         holder.Baixar.setEnabled(false);
    }


    // botão baixar
    holder.Baixar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int clickPosition = (int) v.getTag();

            if (haveNetworkConnection()){
                downloadFile(ImagensVT[clickPosition],nomes[clickPosition]);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Imagem " + (clickPosition+1)+" Baixando!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Não há internet por favor conecte-se!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    }); ...... restante do código      }
    });
```

Esse é um trecho do meu código,esse position me retorna a posição das imagens, ao todo são 21 imagens na lista, meu problema é que no if acima `if(ChecandoseExisteIMG(nomes[position]))` ele verifica se a imagem existe na memória interna se a imagem estiver na memória do aparelho já baixada ele vai setar o botão como baixado e pra não ser clicável mais, porém to obtendo um problema muito chato por exemplo baixei uma foto, de posição 0

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ai funcionou corretamento porém não baixei nenhuma foto a mais além desta, e na pasta que criei quando ele baixa as foto só tem a foto que realmente baixei, 
porém me deparo com isso [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

depois na lista de posição 7 ele vai e seta novamente sendo que a imagem não está baixada

esse é meu vetor dos nomes das imagens:

```
String [] nomes = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21"};
```

gostaria de saber como resolver esse problema, não to entendo porque ele ta fazendo isso, a cada 8 números ele seta novamente oque está dentro do if ChecandoseExisteImg....

Esse vetor de String é apenas um vetor para nomear as imagens, e nesse caso ele pega o nome de acordo com a posição para verificar se a imagem está na memória interna..

Já olhei se poderia ser algo no método de checar e não vi nada lá, o int position do OnBindViewHolder funciona corretamente tb pois testei ele com um TOAST que mostra como que ele ta sendo atualizado, fiz o teste e ele os Toast´s de 0 a 20 que mostra que as 21 posições estão funcionando corretamente, quem tiver como ajudar agradeço..

Caso precisem de mais algo eu edito a postagem...

Atualizado - Métodos que verifica se tem imagem

```
 public static boolean ChecandoseExisteIMG(String ImagenNome)
{
    Bitmap b = null ;
    File file = getImage("/"+ImagenNome+".jpg");
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

    if (path != null)
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);


    if(b == null ||  b.equals(""))
    {
        return false ;
    }
    return true ;
}

// pegando imagem caso tenha
public static File getImage(String imagename) {

    File mediaImage = null;
    try {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root);
        if (!myDir.exists())
            return null;

        mediaImage = new File(myDir.getPath() + "/PixelWallpapers"+imagename);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mediaImage;
}
```

ViewHolder

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
    Button Baixar;
    Button aplicar;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        aplicar=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.aplicar);
        Baixar = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.baixarimg);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_imageview);

    }
}
```

Comment: Consegue adicionar o codigo do metodo que checa se a imagem existe? Provavelmente o erro está ali

Comment: Atualizei @leofontes

Comment: Poderia postar o seu ViewHolder?

Comment: @CleitonOliveira adicionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, não sei muito bem oque aconteceu antes eu havia tentando desta maneira :

```
if (ChecandoseExisteIMG(nomes[position])){
     holder.Baixar.setText("Baixado.");
     holder.Baixar.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Agora fiz assim, podia ter feito isto desdo início rs, mais pelo menos quebrei a cabeça e consegui resolver agora minha lista ele só seta oque realmente tem no código, o problema não está nos métodos e sim com alguma coisa relacionada a posição dos buttons...

```
holder.Baixar.setEnabled(!Existe(nomes[position]));
```

Pode não ter sido a melhor solução, mais pelo menos desativar consegui :)

e também otimizei tava usando dois métodos atoa pra verificar imagem claro que eu reaproveitei eles de outro modo pois eu preciso obter oque já foi salvo, para a função de verificar eu fiz assim:

```
public boolean Existe(String nome){

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root);

    boolean exists = new File(myDir.getPath() + "/PixelWallpapers" +"/"+nome+".jpg").exists();

    return exists;
}
```